# Finding the nearest quantity based on price and amount to get

Tags: math, economics

I've got a small maths problem in which I need to determine a quantity based on a cost price and a final amount.

Now this is easy in theory as it's simply final amount/actual cost = quantity, except in my case the actual cost changes based on the quantity.

Quantity = Final Amount / (Item Cost + Overhead Cost) where the overhead cost is on a sliding scale.

An example would be
If i want to make $500 for selling sheep, and the base price for each sheep is say $50, but the cost of selling one sheep is $5, so the actual cost would be $55 for one sheep, but if i sell 2 sheep then the cost of selling one becomes $7, so the actual cost would be $107 and so on and so forth.

What would be the most optimal way to get to as close to the final amount (but not over) as possible, without having to loop almost unconditionally?

Comment: Wrong place for your question.  Try the math exchange.  Also, calculus.

Comment: The overhead costs aren't quite clear. Is the $7 the cost for selling each sheep, as the wording suggests, or the total cost for selling both the sheep, as the final cost suggests? That is, is there an economy of scale or a diseconomy of scale?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that your overhead cost is always non-negative and monotonic you know that

```
0 <= Quantity <= Final Amount/Item Cost
```

Therefore, a [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the overhead cost is a function of the quantity sold. That means that your equation is in a form that is easy to iterate. You make an initial guess as to the quantity, plug it into the right hand side of the equation, and use it to get a new guess at the quantity. Once the quantity stabilizes, you've reached a fixed point and can stop.

For the sheep-selling example with an economy of scale in the overhead, I'd begin by calculating the number of sheep assuming minimal overhead costs. This might be right, or it might overestimate. The number of updates needed for the process isn't clear in advance, but I'd expect rapid convergence.

Here's how it might look in Python written to be as pseudocode-like as I can make it:

```
import math

def overhead(n):
    # Not given in problem, so I can't give an implementation
    raise NotImplementedError("Sorry, don't know what this is")

def rhs(n, u, t):
    return math.floor(t / (u + overhead(n)))

def best_quantity(unit_cost, total_cost, min_overhead):
    prev_guess = 0
    current_guess = math.floor(total_cost / (unit_cost + min_overhead)) 
    while (current_guess != prev_guess):
        prev_guess = current_guess
        current_guess = rhs(current_guess, unit_cost, total_cost)
    return current_guess

print best_quantity(50.0, 500.0, 0.0)
```